# Rails multiple controller actions

Tags: ruby-on-rails

What is the Rails way for dealing with "multiple controller actions"? In my application i have a special "shopping cart" flow, that has influence on several models. Basically the flow is available to a special kind of user when he/she is logged in, and goes like this:

1. Add a user.

   - Here it's possible to "add a user". If you know about Basecamp, this step is a bit like adding people to a project. So at this step i'm thinking in terms of a user resource.
2. Here it's possible to "buy" stuff for each of the previously added users.

   - This is sort of like a basic shopping cart. So, in terms of resources i'm thinking about a "shop" or a "cart".
3. This is a confirmation step. Again i think of this as part of the cart.

After confirmation, several things should happen.

1. The users that were added in step 1, should somehow be activated. That is, they won't be able to login before the are activated.
2. An order should be placed from the buys in step 2.
3. The "stuff" you buy in step 2 is some kind of virtual product. That is, the products appear as "invitations" when the user logs in. The details of this is not too important, and a little difficult to explain. The key point is that, after confirmation, invitations should be created in the database, associated to the users.

Again, the details of the system is a little difficult to explain, but my main question is how this sort of stuff is best implemented in Rails. In involves several steps, and affects several models across all steps.

I've been thinking about doing it with some kind of statemachine. The statemachine would then be responsible for transitioning between the steps or states, and execute the required actions. So i guess i would have a StateMachineController or something, without a model, that would implement the main logic. Is this something to work with? It seems that Rails is really biased towards RESTfull resources, but i can't seem to think of a RESTfull approach for something like the above. Thanks.

Comment: I had an answer underway, but realized it was too vague to be useful.  My general response is that you should keep as much of the state information in your models, and work out the logic there (whether a state machine or just a simple flow).  This sounds a lot like an "invitation" process to me -- you "invite" a potential new user, and give them virtual stuff.  But they can't get the stuff until they sign up and confirm.  This kind of flow is done brilliantly in the Devise gem (and I think there's an "invitable" module).  Check that out for inspiration.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. You are absolutely right about the invitation system. Actually i'm using Railscast #196 as inspiration on that one, since i have my own authentication system and can't / won't use Devise (not that i don't think Devise is nice). Still my main problem is how to deal with "controlling multiple models". I would need something like: After pressing OK in step 3 DO: place order, activate users, send invitations, etc. So potentially a few actions (spanning user, invitation and order models) rolled up in a single transaction. But thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of the controller action as events that users cause.  What happens after that is logic that should typically be associated with one or more models.

So placing an order is something in the Order model, activating a user is in the User model, sending an invitation is in the Invitation model and so on.  There's nothing wrong with having models know about each other.  When an event spans multiple models, I put a method in the one most closely related to the event the user causes, probably a method like "purchase" in Order, and that's what you would call from Order controller.

So if there are dependencies on state in other models, create little methods in them to test (if needed), like `activated?` in User, and others to do the work, like `activate` (that updates the user state), and then "invite" in Invitation that saves a new invitation that's associated with the user, and so on.  If they fail, make sure they raise an exception.

Once you have a bunch of nice granular methods, you can bundle them together, even wrapping them in a transaction in your `Order#purchase` method.  Something like

```
def purchase(user, stuff, invitee)
  Order.transaction do
    begin
      invitee.activate
      invitation = Invitation.create! {:invitee => invitee, :stuff => stuff, :invited_by => user }
      # You can't roll back an email, so do this after the others have worked without exception
      invitation.send
    rescue
      ActiveRecord::Rollback
    end
  end
end
```

By doing it all in a transaction, your data is either all correct, or not.

Somethin' like that?

Comment: I think i get what you mean. So, having models "comunicate" like that, i think i can make it work. I'm pretty new to Rails, and the hardest part about learning it, i think, is understanding what is "good" rails and what is "bad" rails. By the way, is there some sort of Oberver pattern in Rails? Thanks.

Comment: Well, guess i could just Google the Rails observer pattern :)

Comment: To see "good Rails" look at the source code of gems and of Rails itself.  Mostly it's good if it looks good -- no, seriously.  Short little methods, clean consistent, etc.  Yes, Rails has Observers, but I don't get the sense that they are widely used -- they're good for doing things like decoupling email sending.  Sort of in between might be before/after/around filters -- not exactly the same, but seems to be the more common way to avoid too much if/else logic from messing up otherwise simple methods.